# Can't plot with gnuplot on my Mac

Tags: macos, display, x11, open-source

I am trying to plot with gnuplot on my Mac (OS X 10.8.5). I have installed X11 and XQuartz 2.7.4 and after that I installed gnuplot, but unfortunately gnuplot couldn't plot.

Simple plots like the following fail to render and have no error message to help understand what is amiss:

```
 [1/10/13 $gnuplot >plot sin(x)
```

Comment: Can you say more specifically what isn't working? Perhaps the commands you are using, error messages, and results?

Comment: when I want to plot sin(x) in gnuplot, it can not plot and it goes to the next line without any error. $gnuplot
>plot sin(x)
>

Comment: Please edit the pertinent details into the body of the question. Comments get cleared from time to time and we'd hate to lose the problem when that happens here.

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Comment: Does xterm give you a xterminal ?

Comment: This is not only Mountain-lion problem. This is much more general problem in OS X and its dipslay. Qt should be added as a tag, since x11 is there.

Answer (score 50):

The same thing happened to me, but then I ran

```
brew uninstall gnuplot; brew install gnuplot --with-x11
```

and installed [XQuartz](https://xquartz.macosforge.org). Now `gnuplot` supports the `x11` terminal:

[image]

You can also save the output to a file and use `qlmanage -p`:

```
gnuplot -e 'set term png; set output "/tmp/plot.png"; plot sin(x)'; qlmanage -p /tmp/plot.png
```

`qlmanage -p` shows a sandboxing error in 10.9 and prints some unnecessary text to STDOUT, so I use a function like `ql() { qlmanage -p "$@"&>/dev/null; }` in shells.

A third option is to use `set term dumb` for plain text output.

Comment: Maybe I'm slow today, but I spent a good 15 minutes in the gnuplot docs looking for a simple example like this .. or maybe the docs make some assumptions about the audience and I'm not one of them :)

Comment: xQuartz is heavy and somehow homebrew doesn't package it. I went with --qt option instead `bew install gnuplot --qt` and it works fine now.

Comment: Option name has changed to `--with-x11` but I cannot make an edit of only two characters.

Comment: Note that sometimes you need to **log out** and log back in after installing XQuartz. (don't know why, but it didn't set the $DISPLAY variable correctly until I logged out) Also, very useful to install XQuartz is http://caskroom.io/:  `brew cask install xquartz`

Comment: doesn't work for OS X Yosemite

Comment: Just so it's clear. You don't need the  --with-x11 flag if you want to output to a png (or at least I didn't).

Comment: does not work on OS X El Capitan

Comment: Instead of lettings thousands of users install a half-broken version of gnuplot, with many dependencies but many terminals missing, why aren't there binaries available?

Answer (score 24):

In OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and El Capitan 10.11.2, the Gnuplot does not package with XQuartz.
Answer in *bibstha*'s comment.
Much more robust window manager is in *qt* and it works

```
 brew uninstall gnuplot
 brew install gnuplot --with-qt
```

Note that using `--qt` is deprecated now.

Comment: Just as a side note, `Warning: gnuplot: --qt was deprecated; using --with-qt instead!`

Comment: @vitaly Interesting. I did not get that warning or I ignored. I changed the command.

Comment: --qt must have been valid at some point and then it was deprecated

Comment: Why not to choose both: `brew install gnuplot --with-qt  --with-x11`.

Comment: Because of the bug having X11 in Yosemite. Not using at the moment Yosemite so cannot test with the latest update.

Answer (score 5):

Are you running this from a Terminal window, or an X11 window? The terminal will launch X11 separately to show the plot, so it may not be immediate (or visible). Does X11 get launched at all when you type your `plot` command?

If you try it in an X11 window, the result should be more immediate.

Also, if you used macports to install it originally, I would recommend using `homebrew` instead:

```
brew install gnuplot
```

**EDIT**: To check where the output is going, you could direct your results to a file:

```
set terminal png
set output 'testimage.png'
plot sin(x)
exit
```

Then see if a file called `testimage.png` contains your plot.
You could also try specifying the terminal with:

```
set terminal x11
```

Comment: Yes, you are right and the last > is not part of my command. Moreover, I am running from a both Terminal window and X11 window separately, but none of them could plot.

Comment: Then I would try reinstalling with `brew`. It is hard to diagnose without knowing more about your installation.

Comment: (Updated answer with another thing to test...)

Comment: Why does replacing macports by brew make a difference they both work - both much better than doing on your own

Comment: In my experience I have problems with libraries and dependencies when I use macports, so have stopped doing so...

Answer (score 1):

In Yosemite, 
Initially, I had quartz and gunplot 5.0.0 installed. However, I could not load my x11 window (everything else was file-X11 was somehow unknown).
Here is a workaround that 'worked for me'.

Go to the gunplot source folder

```
make clean; 
make uninstall
```

then in the "configure" file  under the following lines

```
# Standard set of common directories for X headers.

# Check X11 before X11Rn because it is often a symlink to the current release.

---added the location of my X11 files also  
/opt/X11/include
```

now run

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

worked perfectly for me as you see below

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 0    last modified 2015-01-01 

Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2015
Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')
```

Terminal type `set to 'x11'`.

Comment: How did you install X11 /opt is not usual I think

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  After downloading gunplot 5.0 and installing under Yosemite 10.10.2, gnuplot couldn't "load" the x11 terminal.  After pointing the configure file
to /opt/X11/include (reconfiguring, remaking, and reinstalling) every worked fine.
(I was surprised, too, that X11 is in /opt/X11.)

Comment: Why not use a quartz backend rather than X11

Answer (score 0):

Most of the advice here shows how to install/reinstall GNUPlot via `brew`. If you have an installation of GNUPlot and are unsure what terminal its using you can determine this like so:

```
$ gnuplot <<<'show terminal'

   terminal type is qt 0 font "Sans,9"
```

At which point we now know we're using the `qt` terminal type. With thin information now in hand you can decide on which course of action to take, either following one of the other answers to re-install GNUPlot via `brew` or configuring your existing terminal in whatever way you want via the `set terminal ....` . command.