# Gnuplot with xterm in yosemite

Tags: macos, homebrew

I installed gnuplot on my yosemite system using brew. When I try to plot `cos(x)` the way I would on ubuntu, I get this:

```
gnuplot> plot cos(x)
WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.
No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.
```

I also notice that when gnuplot loads, it says `Terminal type set to 'unknown'`. I would like to load the graphs in a new window, so I tried `set terminal xterm`, which seems to work at first glance, given the message `Terminal type set to 'xterm'`. But then I try plotting again, and it produces garbage:

[image]

How do I get the terminal to function correctly, as it does on ubuntu?

Comment: As an aside, if you want to get away from X11 and remembering if you are in xterm or terminal app, just switch `gnuplot` to use qt - it sets up the terminal properly and one shot install: `brew reinstall gnuplot --with-qt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if you resolved, but seems strange to me you want to plot in the `xterm` terminal...
Perhaps you want to display in the `x11` terminal, you'll then find this discussion useful: [Can't plot with gnuplot on my Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/cant-plot-with-gnuplot-on-my-mac)

Comment: I am trying `x11` but it says `unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list` despite the fact that I have `x11` installed on my system.

Comment: Ok, I followed the steps in the other post. Thanks for pointing out that I was confusing `xterm` with `x11`.

Comment: you're welcome! gnuplot is always a little shady but is a powerful piece of software, never found something as powerful and flexible as it.