# Using gnuplot terminal on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, open-source

I just installed **gnuplot** and I am trying to set the default terminal view.  On the wikipedia page for gnuplot, there is an [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot#/media/File:Gnuplot-in-action.png) with a graph:

[image]

Which terminal view is shown in the image at the link?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/cant-plot-with-gnuplot-on-my-mac

Comment: @patrix You rock - that's so cool `qt` works too. Re-evaluating X11 for this :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image looks more like `qt` than X11, so you could reinstall gnu plot to call the qt graphics library:

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --with-qt5
```

That's much simpler than getting XQuartz and X11 running since homebrew installs everything you need.

[image]

If you wanted to go X11 *for reasons*, then here is a nice tutorial and links to the visualization tools that should work on recent OS X versions.

- https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot

It uses X11 for the visualization and should help you get your graph on.

1. `http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/` Install the package that gets downloaded, then
2. `brew rm gnuplot && brew install gnuplot --with-x11`

Then start XQuartz, make a new xterm and run a script like this in the xterm window running `gnuplot`:

```
set terminal x11
set title "Some Math Functions"
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-2:2]
set zeroaxis
plot (x/4)**2, sin(x), 1/x
```

Skip the "set terminal" line if you are using qt as it gets set for you when gnuplot starts. If you need monochrome, you can also `set terminal xterm`.

Comment: Use `set terminal x11` if you want to get color output under X11 :-)

Comment: @patrix Yay - I wondered why I was seeing monochrome. Chapeau!

Comment: Note that ```--with-qt``` is deprecated and now you want ```--with-qt5```